# Cuál es la forma correcta de agregar un route usando slim framework

Tags: php, api, rest, slim

Tengo un archivo llamado **app/route/empleados_route.php** que tiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    $app->group('/empleados', function(){
        $this->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args){
            echo "Listado de empleados de prueba!";
        });
    });
?>
```

En el **index.php** tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

    require '../vendor/autoload.php';

    $app = new \Slim\App;

    require '../app/route/empleados_route.php';

    $app->run();
?>
```

Cuando ejecuto no me muestra nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si incluyo el código de **empleados_route.php** dentro del **index.php** entonces funciona correctamente.

Mi pregunta es: cómo es la forma correcta de organizar los archivos y que funcionen correctamente? es decir, los routes, models, etc.

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Has probado a cambiar la url del require? Si la carpeta app esta a la par que el index los `..`sobran; `/app/route/empleados_route.php`

Comment: No está a la par, index.php está dentro de public y public si que está a la par de app. Gracias.

Comment: Mete la carpeta app dentro de public y cambia la url. Seguramente el servidor no esta pudiendo acceder a la carpeta fuera de public.

Comment: La he cambiado y he cambiado la URL pero sigue mostrando el mismo mensaje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mas correcto seria usar los "use" que le corresponden

```
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
```

con estos no te saldria el error y seguirias definiendo las variables

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he solucionado,

Resulta que tenia que quitar las referencias a Request y Response de la función ya que no tienen alcance en el archivo. El código final queda de la siguiente manera:

antes:

```
$app->group('/empleados', function(){
    $this->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args){
        echo "Listado de empleados!";
    });
});
```

después:

```
$app->group('/empleados', function(){
    $this->get('/', function ($request, $response, array $args){
        echo "Listado de empleados!";
    });
});
```